# How do I add sass-lint to my angular-cli.json file?

Tags: angular, sass, webpack, angular-cli, sass-lint

I'm using this seed app: https://github.com/2sic/app-tutorial-angular4-hello-dnn

I've installed sass-lint: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-lint

But not sure how to add this to my angular-cli.json file.

I've using **angular version 4**, **webpack**, with **typescript** and **sass** for this example.

I've added a "sass-lint.yml" file to my root with the default settings.

**This is my angular-cli.json file:**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "my-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is my solution:

**1. package.json**

```
"sass-lint": "./node_modules/sass-lint/bin/sass-lint.js -c src/sass-lint.yml -v -q",
"lint": "npm run sass-lint && ng lint",
```

**2. src/sass-lint.yml**

```
files:
  include: '**/src/**/*.s+(a|c)ss'
```

**3. After these changes, you can run all linting rules in a single command**

```
npm run lint
```

---

### Reference Files:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng lint && ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test --browsers Chrome",
    "sass-lint": "./node_modules/sass-lint/bin/sass-lint.js -c src/sass-lint.yml -v -q",
    "lint": "npm run sass-lint && ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "release": "npm run lint && ng test --watch=false --cc --browsers Chrome && ng build --prod",
    "preflight": "npm run lint && ng test --watch=false --cc --browsers ChromeHeadless && ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "class-transformer": "^0.1.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.4.3",
    "primeng": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.15",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-karma-sonar": "~0.2.27",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.3.0",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter": "^0.0.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.1",
    "sass-lint": "^1.10.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.2"
  }
}
```

**src/sass-lint.yml**

```
options:
  formatter: stylish
files:
  include: '**/src/**/*.s+(a|c)ss'
rules:
  # Extends
  extends-before-mixins: 1
  extends-before-declarations: 1
  placeholder-in-extend: 1

  # Mixins
  mixins-before-declarations: 1

  # Line Spacing
  one-declaration-per-line: 1
  empty-line-between-blocks: 1
  single-line-per-selector: 1

  # Disallows
  no-attribute-selectors: 0
  no-color-hex: 0
  no-color-keywords: 1
  no-color-literals: 1
  no-combinators: 0
  no-css-comments: 1
  no-debug: 1
  no-disallowed-properties: 0
  no-duplicate-properties: 1
  no-empty-rulesets: 1
  no-extends: 0
  no-ids: 1
  no-important: 1
  no-invalid-hex: 1
  no-mergeable-selectors: 1
  no-misspelled-properties: 1
  no-qualifying-elements: 1
  no-trailing-whitespace: 1
  no-trailing-zero: 1
  no-transition-all: 1
  no-universal-selectors: 0
  no-url-domains: 1
  no-url-protocols: 1
  no-vendor-prefixes: 1
  no-warn: 1
  property-units: 0

  # Nesting
  declarations-before-nesting: 1
  force-attribute-nesting: 1
  force-element-nesting: 1
  force-pseudo-nesting: 1

  # Name Formats
  class-name-format: 1
  function-name-format: 1
  id-name-format: 0
  mixin-name-format: 1
  placeholder-name-format: 1
  variable-name-format: 1

  # Style Guide
  attribute-quotes: 1
  bem-depth: 0
  border-zero: 1
  brace-style: 1
  clean-import-paths: 1
  empty-args: 1
  hex-length: 1
  hex-notation: 1
  indentation: 1
  leading-zero: 1
  max-line-length: 0
  max-file-line-count: 0
  nesting-depth: 1
  property-sort-order: 1
  pseudo-element: 1
  quotes: 1
  shorthand-values: 1
  url-quotes: 1
  variable-for-property: 1
  zero-unit: 1

  # Inner Spacing
  space-after-comma: 1
  space-before-colon: 1
  space-after-colon: 1
  space-before-brace: 1
  space-before-bang: 1
  space-after-bang: 1
  space-between-parens: 1
  space-around-operator: 1

  # Final Items
  trailing-semicolon: 1
  final-newline: 1
```

Comment: I just would suggest adding ignore on node_modules: ignore:
    - 'node_modules/**/*.*'  in the 'files' section

Comment: This method doesn't error if you save a file so have to remember to run npm lint... Do you know a way to hook into the watch event so it runs when you save SCSS files?

Comment: This works, but I had to change my script to the following `"sass-lint -c sass-lint.yml -v -q"`

Comment: If you are using VSCode, this extension works great to underline violaions in the editor: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glen-84.sass-lint

Comment: getting this error, > ./node_modules/sass-lint/bin/sass-lint.js -c src/sass-lint.yml -v -q

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @Govindaraj: Did you see the comment from "Chris Barr" above? You have to replace the command so that node calls sass-lint. "sass-lint": "sass-lint -c sass-lint.yml -v -q". And then call "npm run sass-lint" from a command line.

Comment: In step 1 there's also a typo. Shouldn't `npm run saas-lint` be `npm run sass-lint`?